# Only 1 card is displaying on screen instead or 4 cards in row react and antd. Help I'm new at this

Tags: reactjs, api, grid, antd

I'm using antd and little bit of bootstrap. please find the fault. I'm making this project from this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VihRQ_uhHtE&t=1915s . all the files for this movie page is shown below.

Here is the main page landingcomponent.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {API_URL, API_KEY, IMAGE_URL} from '../../config/keys';
import {Typography, Row} from 'antd';
import MainImage from './MainImage';
import GridCard from './GridCard';

const {Title} = Typography;

function LandingPage() {
const [Movies, setMovies] = useState([])

useEffect( () => {

    fetch(`${API_URL}movie/popular?api_key=${API_KEY}&language=en-US&page=1`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        setMovies(response.results);
    })
}, [])

return(
    <div style={{width:'100%'}}>
    {Movies[0] &&
    <MainImage image={`${IMAGE_URL}original${Movies[0].backdrop_path}`}
     title={Movies[0].original_title}
     text={Movies[0].overview} />}

    <div className= "m-2">
        <Title className='font-weight-bolder' style={{ color: 'black' }}>Latest Movies</Title>
        <div>
            <Row gutter={[16,16]}>
                {Movies && Movies.map((movie, index) => (
                    <React.Fragment key={index}>
                        <GridCard 
                                image={movie.poster_path && `${IMAGE_URL}original${movie.poster_path}`}
                                movieId={movie.id}
                        />
                    </React.Fragment>
                ))}
            </Row>
            <div className="text-center">
                <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick>Load More</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
);

}

export default LandingPage;
```

and this is my gridcard.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Col} from 'antd'

function GridCard(props) {
return (
    <Col lg={6} md={8} xs={24}>
        <div className="position-relative">
            <a href={`/movie/${props.movieId}`}>
                <img style={{ width:'100%', height:'300px'}} alt="image" src={props.image} />
            </a>
        </div>
    </Col>
)
}

export default GridCard;
```

also last MainImage.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import {Typography, Row} from 'antd';

const {Title} = Typography;

function MainImage(props) {
return(
    <div className="img-responsive position-relative"
        style={{
            background: `url('${props.image}'), #1c1e1c`,
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            height: '50vh',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            width: '100%',
        }}
    >
        <div>
            <div className='position-absolute' style={{ maxWidth:'450px', bottom: '2rem', marginLeft: '2rem' }} >
                <Title className='h1' level={2}> {props.title} </Title>
                <p style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: '1rem' }}  > {props.text} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
}

export default MainImage;
```

Comment: Could you make a https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new ?

Comment: It will take forever and API keys are also part of this. can't you help me otherwise?

Comment: You can copy a real response from the API and paste it as a variable in sandbox, like `const sampleAPIResponse = ''`. I couldn't notice what's wrong with your code by looking at it...

Comment: you can go to my github repo [link](https://github.com/MoviesAndTvShowsTracker/ShowTracker) just go to main folder. you'll find movies component there